# Make all tooltips for tool buttons in editor uniform

Tags: feature-request, design, editor, tooltips

Each tool button for an edit window which changes text body contains a tooltip with a keyboard hotkey. In all cases except "snippet" hotkey format is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> `+` <kbd>Letter</kbd>, for the snippet button `-` (minus) is used to combine keys:

> [image: B]

> [image: I]

> [image: M]

My (I know it's minor) request is to replace minus symbol with plus for the snippet tooltip for conformity.

For more uniform also `-` (minus) symbol could be added between action description and hotkey combination itself as it's made for <kbd>Redo</kbd> and <kbd>Undo</kbd> buttons:

> [image: Redo]